# Encrypting or Encoding content in jdmk.security

Tags: java, snmp, snmp-trap, jdmk

I'm coding a java program, using the JDMK 5.1 toolkit, to send SNMPv3 traps and the jdmk security file (jdmk.security.file) I seem to need to create, and have in place, to do so currently has the authorization and privacy keys in the clear.

How can I cause those values, which I consider to be passwords, be secured and still be usable by the toolkit when it reads that data from the file?

The documentation says you may specify "Any text password or any hexadecimal key starting with 0x" for those values but does not elaborate.